# C# - Tricky serial raw data must be stored to a struct

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, serial-port

I am stuck trying to extract data from raw data I get from a serial server. RegEx is not my game and I feel like spinning around... Well here's the template of my servers response:

```
TIME STAMP dd/MM/YY HH:mm:ss

SAMPLING DATA IN SLOT 1 - COMS

    Dev 1

        Par 1: XXXXXX  //Signed integers
            .
            .
            .
        Par n: XXXXXX  //Signed integers
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    Dev n

        Par 1: XXXXXX  //Signed integers
            .
            .
            .
        Par n: XXXXXX  //Signed integers

DATA SLOT 1 SAMPLED
.
.
.
.
.
.
SAMPLING DATA IN SLOT n - COMS

    Dev n

        Par 1: XXXXXX  //Signed integers
            .
            .
            .
        Par n: XXXXXX  //Signed integers
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    Dev n

        Par 1: XXXXXX  //Signed integers
            .
            .
            .
        Par n: XXXXXX  //Signed integers

DATA SLOT n SAMPLED

ALL BOARDS COMPLETED
```

What I want to achieve is to store the above data to Structs (C#)

Below are the few things I achieved:

```
string strRegex = @"Par([^:]*): ([^\s]*)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @DataStream;
foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if (myMatch.Success)
    {
        SetText(myMatch.Value + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

DataStream = "";
```

This extracts **Par n: XXXXXX**

A real world output is:

```
SAMPLING DATA IN SLOT 3 - COMS 

     Dev 1 

     Par 0: 5000 

     Par 6: 1041 

     Par 7: 1041 

     Par 8: 1032 

     Par 19: 0 

     Par 20: 0 

     Par 21: 0 

     Par 28: -2147483648 

     Par 29: -2147483648
```

......

==============EDIT w/SOLUTION (Igor's Answer)======================

Thanks Igor! I made some (dumb) adjustments so it includes the SLOT information. Just for the other C# devs to know, I used the following bits of code (Multiline MUST be checked):

```
string strRegex = @"(SLOT [0-9] - COMS )?\s*(\w+)\s+(\d+)(?::\s+(-?\d+))?\s*$";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Did you want to print only `xxxxx`?

Comment: Why do you tag a C# question C??

Comment: You're right, but...RegEx is the crucial thing. Feel free to write your answer in C...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this regex for parsing a 'real world output': `^\s*(\w+)\s+(\d+)(?::\s+(-?\d+))?\s*$`

It won't match empty lines and status message.
Here's group breakdown for the rest:

```
Input                         \1     \2      \3
'     Dev 1 '                 'Dev'  '1'     ''
'     Par 0: 5000 '           'Par'  '0'     '5000'
'     Par 6: 1041 '           'Par'  '6'     '1041'
'     Par 7: 1041 '           'Par'  '7'     '1041'
'     Par 8: 1032 '           'Par'  '8'     '1032'
'     Par 19: 0 '             'Par'  '19'    '0'
'     Par 20: 0 '             'Par'  '20'    '0'
'     Par 21: 0 '             'Par'  '21'    '0'
'     Par 28: -2147483648 '   'Par'  '28'    '-2147483648'
'     Par 29: -2147483648 '   'Par'  '29'    '-2147483648'
```

If you plan to get familiar with regexes, [this is good starting point](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Cheers!

Comment: Very good regex! https://regex101.com/r/aA1sB5/1 is a working demo with your expression.